# How to get MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss format in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to get datetime as **Jan 17 2013  4:34:59** with time in 24 hrs format

Comment: This is best done in the application code when displaying - why do you need to do this in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 108) AS [Mon DD, YYYY]
```